# formik form validation not working reactjs

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

following this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNiJkjEwmpw&t=1578s on formik form validation and running into an issue when implementing validation 
`validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email().required(),
    password: Yup.string().min(6).required()
  }),`

i get no error messages on my local environment but on my codesandbox i get the following error 
`TypeError
Cannot read property 'object' of undefined`

which is pretty straight forward but im not knowledgable enough to debug (still new to react and formik) thanks for all the help here below is full source code & also here is a link to codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/kw4x2k62rv

```
import React from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormFeedback } from 'reactstrap';
import { withFormik, Field } from 'formik';
import Yup from 'yup';

const App = ({
  values,
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  errors,
  touched
}) =>
  (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="fname">First Name</Label>
        <Input
          value={values.fname}
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          id="fname"
          placeholder="first name"
          autoComplete="first name"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="lname">Last Name</Label>
        <Input
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.lname}
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          id="lname"
          placeholder="last name"
          autoComplete="last name"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="email">Email</Label>
        <Input
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.email}
          type="email"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="email"
          autoComplete="email"
        />
        {  touched.email && errors.email && <FormFeedback>Oh noes! that name is already taken</FormFeedback> }
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="password">Password</Label>
        <Input
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="password"
          value={values.password}
          name="password"
          id="password"
          placeholder="password"
          autoComplete="password"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</Label>
        <Input
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.confirmPassword}
          type="password"
          name="confirmPassword"
          id="confirmPassword"
          placeholder="confirm password"
          autoComplete="confirm password"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>
          <Field type="checkbox" name="tos" checked={values.tos} />
          Check me out
        </Label>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button> Submit </Button>
    </Form>
  )

const FormikApp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues({ email, password, fname, lname, confirmPassword, tos }) {
    return {
      email: email || '',
      password: password || '',
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword || '',
      fname: fname || '',
      lname: lname || '',
      tos: tos || false
    }
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email().required(),
    password: Yup.string().min(6).required()
  }),
  handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }
})(App)

export default FormikApp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it works locally and not on codesandbox but I can tell you know it isn't working on codesandbox.

`Yup` does not have a default export e.g. `export { string, object etc }`. See: https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/src/index.js

Doing `import Yup from 'yup'` would mean that `Yup` is `undefined`. If you wanted to using import syntax you could do `import * as yup from 'yup'` then do `yup.object()` or use require - `var yup = require('yup')`

Comment: so i added that fix to my codepen and everything looks fine but now whenever i post the form nothing console logs, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as Yup from 'yup'
```

Not sure why that works but I was having the same problem and it worked for me.